# Set indexing path for references

Tags: clion

Is there any way i can tell clion to index every path under my project?
I'm importing an eclipse c project and clion doesn't seem to be able to index correctly and it can't show suggestions/completions/references. Do i have to tamper with the CMakeLists somehow?

Eclipse can see most of these references and includes without any tampering

Answer (score 0):

In Mac OS, when the cursor hang over the undefined symbol, press "Option + Enter" key and it will auto find out where the symbol is in some extra path.